# Different IO performance on mapping drive between mstsc connection and openSSH

Tags: windows, ssh, network-drive

**Situation:**

1. Connect to my Windows host via **mstsc**  (Win10)
2. Mapping network drive using `net use`, let’s say on disk Z
3. Run vdbench, which is an I/O workload generator. It's configured to read files from disk Z
4. Log shows the read performance is about **1000mb/s**
5. Now connect to the same host via **openSSH**
6. Repeat **step2-3**, commands are the same. The mapping drive user, the disk and the folder where files located are identical, and the previous execution has been stopped
7. Now the read performance is about **800mb/s**, no matter how many times I've tried, it's always lower than using mstsc.

I have to run the tool with ssh.

**Tried**

- My other hosts works fine. SSH config looks the same bewteen them and my problematic hosts.

---

I figure that it might have something to do with **mapping drive AND ssh**, because I also tried reading files from local, and they gave the same performance.